# Undefined reference to Boost Library only on remote machine

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Issue: my files compile on my local virtual machine (LVM) but not on the Institute server (IS).

LVM and IS have the same version of Boost library installed (Installed from source).

With `bashrc` file updated with the environment variables `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for `Boost` as follows:

On LVM:

```
PATH=/home/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

On IS:

```
PATH=/user/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/user/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Files are compiled on LVM with the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 benchmark_ad_tree.cpp blank_scoring_function.cpp fnml_scoring_function.cpp log_likelihood_calculator.cpp bdeu_scoring_function.cpp bayesian_network.cpp score_calculator.cpp ad_tree.cpp -o check  -L /home/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib/*.so
```

However, when the same command is used to compile the same code on IS it throws the following bunch of exceptions:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 benchmark_ad_tree.cpp blank_scoring_function.cpp fnml_scoring_function.cpp log_likelihood_calculator.cpp bdeu_scoring_function.cpp bayesian_network.cpp score_calculator.cpp ad_tree.cpp -o check  /user/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib/*.so
```

Update:
Following the suggestion from @John Zwinck (in the answer section).

I have updated the compiling command to

Exceptions raised:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 benchmark_ad_tree.cpp blank_scoring_function.cpp fnml_scoring_function.cpp log_likelihood_calculator.cpp bdeu_scoring_function.cpp bayesian_network.cpp score_calculator.cpp ad_tree.cpp -o check -L /user/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib -lboost_numpy -lboost_python  -lboost_thread
```

Raised exception:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWojrSj.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/user/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.so.1.64.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong linker argument:

```
-L /home/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib/*.so
```

That should be:

```
-L /home/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib -l boost_numpy -l boost_python
```

There is no need to put Boost in your `PATH`, and you should not set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` except as a last resort.

You should never use shell wildcards (`*`) as part of a build command.

Comment: I tried the following command :`g++ -std=c++11 -O3 benchmark_ad_tree.cpp blank_scoring_function.cpp fnml_scoring_function.cpp log_likelihood_calculator.cpp bdeu_scoring_function.cpp bayesian_network.cpp score_calculator.cpp ad_tree.cpp -o check -L /user/X/my_lib/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib -lboost_numpy -lboost_python`..... I have updated the post with the exception I got

Comment: U probly need `-lboost_system` as well

Comment: @letsBeePolite: As Chris Beck explains, you need to link all the libraries you need.  It's as simple as that.  Rather than  posting back here again with each new error, think about what the error means and how you can fix it.  In this case, by adding `-l boost_system`.